# Allowing an Electron-hosted webapp to call window.open and to use the result as if it were a regular Chrome window

Tags: javascript, node.js, window, electron

The webapp that I'm hosting in Electron's webview tag makes calls to `window.open`. However, [since](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6617) `window.open` can't be invoked from inside of an iframe in Electron, I am forced to override `window.open`, so that it sends a message to the renderer process that hosts the webapp and tells it to invoke `window.open` and send back the result.

From my renderer: `webContents.send("my-channel", myWindow);`

However, it doesn't appear that I can simply send back the entire window to the webapp. The window that gets sent to the webapp doesn't have any of the functions that [BrowserWindowProxy](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window-proxy.md) is supposed to have (e.g. `close`). I imagine that it would be strange if it did have a `close`, since `close` would need to know to escape the webapp (through some means) and alert Electron's renderer/main process that a window needs to be closed.

I want the `window` that is sent to the webapp to behave like a more-or-less regular Chrome window (namely, I want it to have the same public api). So, my first question was how to get such a window to the webapp.

The solution I came up with is the following. I still call `window.open` in the renderer process, but instead of passing back the resulting window, I pass back an object that has a windowId property, which is set to the window's id. When that object gets to the webapp, it goes through a little intermediary that sees the window object and sets some properties (like `close`, `focus`) that internally send a message to the renderer process to perform the relevant operation (via a function exposed through the preload script). Something like:

```
myWindow = {
    windowId: 1,
    close: function() {
        sendActionFromWebviewToMain("close", this.windowId);
    }
}
```

The next problem I ran into was that the window returned by Electron's `window.open`, unlike the one returned by `new BrowserWindow(...)`, does not appear to have an id. The [source code](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/915f6a6f54b8237226d86c0e3f3e80d72dbdc957/lib/renderer/window-setup.js#L57) references a guestId, but I have no way of accessing it.

How can I use `window.open` to create a window that the webapp can interact with? Am I forced to create the window using the `BrowserWindow` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has since been fixed.

All I need to do now is set the `nativeWindowOpen` and `allowpopups` attributes on my webview tag, and I can use the native `window.open`.

```
<webview webpreferences="nativeWindowOpen=yes" allowpopups />
```